# Send keys issue using PhantomJS but not with Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, upload, phantomjs

I am currently working with Selenium and Python uploading a file to a website automatically. I always test my code by using the Firefox browser because in that way I can see what happens behind the scenes. Ok, everything seems fine. The image uploads it self and the results are there to see. But when I change browsers. Using PhantomJS, the request seems to get stuck when I send_keys to an element (file uploading element).

I use the following code:

```
'''Image Upload'''

upload_photo_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(upload_photo_field_ID)
image = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images/' + 'img.png')
upload_photo_element.send_keys(image)

time.sleep(5)

upload_photo_reject_button_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(upload_photo_reject_button_ID))
upload_photo_reject_button_element.click()

'''End image upload'''
```

I don't understand why Firefox has no problem handling this. But PhantomJS do.

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the web site public? If not, can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not alone in having [trouble](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/282) [uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752302/selenium-phantomjs-in-python-2-7-file-upload) [files](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4h8vhs/alternative_file_upload_code_to_send_keys_in/) using PhantomJS.

Is the input field visible? Some sites will hide the input field and display another element that can be styled to suit. Doing that prevents uploading files with IE11 - PhantomJS might be the same. You could try making the field visible first. How you do that depends on how it's made invisible. Make sure it's not hidden and doesn't have any CSS styles applied that would hide it.

[Someone else suggested another workaround](http://muratknecht.de/tech/uploading-files-phantomjs-ghostdriver-python/):

> Since uploadFile is broken in PhantomJS, you need to avoid using it. How to do that depends on whether PhantomJS is running on the same machine as your tests.
>
> If it's locally, you could use the PhantomJS driver directly. If you need to use the Remote driver, or if PhantomJS is running remotely, you need to patch the driver to behave as if running locally.
>
> With the Python Web Driver, you do this by setting the attribute _is_remote on the web driver to False. See source. Your code then would look like this:

```
is_remote = webdriver._is_remote
webdriver._is_remote = False
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('input').send_keys(filepath)
webdriver._is_remote = is_remote
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mark Lapierre. Do I have to test this on a 'remote webdriver'? Because when I copy your code I get an error that ._is_remote attribute doesn't exist on the webdriver.

Comment: The input field is not hidden. And the article 'trouble uploading files' seems to match my problem.

Comment: It works for me with phantomjs-prebuilt 2.1.14 from npm, python 3.5.2, and selenium 3.3.3. What version of PhantomJS, Python, and Selenium are you using? Also, 'trouble uploading files' is actually three separate links. Each word is a link. One of the other links might help.

Comment: And no, you don't need to use a remote webdriver.

Comment: I work with PhantomJS version 2.1.1, python 2.7.10 and selenium (3.3.3). 'Files' seems to match my problem, sorry for being unclear. Thanks for your help btw I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem with the help. I just tried with those versions and it worked without the workaround. I also checked for _is_remote and it's there. How are you creating the driver instance? And can you share the HTML or the website?

Comment: thanks for your help. But I am going to stick around with Firefox and let PhantomJS behind. I read some articles, that the speed does not make much of a difference. They say that the headless browser PhantomJS is firstly unreliable against a real browser. And that it hasn't to be faster, just because it doesn't render the page it might be faster in the startup, but not at sending the request. They say that PhantomJS does render the pages but in background. So, I will stick to Firefox. Thank you for your kindness and help I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. And in a little while you'll be able to run [Chrome headless](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5678767817097216), which might work better.